# Xcode UUID Attributes error after updating to version 11

Tags: xcode

After updating Xcode to version 11, I can't compile my code because it shows this error on all my Core Data classes that have a UUID attribute.

```
UUID Attributes feature requires Xcode 9.0 model file format or later [4]
```

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done? Where have you got stuck? [superuser.com/help/how-to-ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also encountered this error after updating to Xcode 11.

I fixed it by changing the Tools Version from Xcode 7 ( in my case ) to Xcode 9 for each .xcdatamodel version in my .xcdatamodeld that uses UUID attributes.

[image: Xcode 11 screenshot of .xcdatamodel File Inspector pane]